# Proof of equality of two statements

Tags: graph-theory

> Let $G$ be a directed graph, where there's a directed path from every
>   point to every other. How to prove that these two statements are
>   equivalent:
>
> a) Graph $G$ has a directed  simple cycle that has even number of edges
>
> b) Graph $G$'s vertices can be painted with two colors (each one with
>   one color) so that for every vertex u, there will be arc $(u,v)$, where
>   v and u are of different colors.

I know that to prove equality, I need to prove that a follows from b and b from a. But how do I do that?

Comment: These two statements actually don't seem equivalent: what if you have a graph G that has a directed cycle with an even number of edges but that also has a single vertex subgraph? Then a) is true but b) is false. Should the cycle in a) maybe contain *all* vertices?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a counter-example to the equality of two statements[image]

This digraph has a directed cycle $C$ with an even number of edges: your condition (a). But there is a vertex (e.g., $v$) with no arc connecting vertices of different colouring.

My guess: Your condition (a) should read: **evey** directed simple cycle that has even number of edges.